# With single table, how do I collapse multiple rows with mutually exclusive column data

Tags: sql

I wish to combine rows of a table, with mutually exclusive column values, retaining all columns:
For example:

```
Name Data1 Data2 Data3 .... DataN
NAM1  6     NULL  NULL ...   NULL
NAM1  NULL  NULL  7    ...   NULL
NAM2  NULL   8    NULL ...   NULL
NAM3  5     NULL  NULL ...   NULL
NAM3  NULL  NULL   9   ...   NULL
NAM3  NULL   4    NULL ...   NULL
NAM4  etc
```

The characteristic of the data on each row of the table only 1 of the values Data1 ... DataN will not be NULL

I want the results to be

```
NAME DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 ... DATAN
NAM1  6     NULL  7    ...  NULL
NAM2  NULL  8     NULL ...  NULL
NAM3  5     4     9    ...  NULL
NAM4
```

Comment: Are you talking about tables in a relational database (and thus about a SQL query) or about a HTML table that you want to collapse?

Comment: results from a pivot query, not HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select Name, MAX(Data1), MAX(Data2), MAX(Data3) from test
group by Name
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, if the columns data for every name are mutually exclusive (at most 1 row has a value for DataX) MIN, MAX, AVG and even SUM will get the correct result